# Real roots of $f(x) = 5 \sqrt x + 37[ \sqrt[27] x] = 1$ in $[0,1]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Find real roots of the following polynomial which belong to the closed interval $[0,1]$ :

$$f(x) = 5 \sqrt x + 37[ \sqrt[27] x] - 1$$

How to approach such a problem? I don't know where to start.

Comment: That is not a polynomial.

Comment: As f is increasing, there will be only one solution.

Comment: If you want a polynomial, do something like $x \to x^{54}$ to start.  further, you’ll need numerical methods.

Comment: Subtract $5\sqrt x$, raise to 27th power, collect terms in $\sqrt x$ on one side, square both sides – then you'll have a polynomial. Of very high degree. Better ideas: 1. Find some software that solve equations. 2. Learn about numerical methods, like Newton's Method.

Comment: Start  at 1/25..

Comment: Are the brackets in the second term meant to represent the floor function? If so, you can simplify the equation by noting that $x=1$ does not work, and the second term is $0$ on the rest of the interval.

Comment: Your equation has two equality symbols, so what **actually** are you asking?

Comment: I'm sorry about the mistake I made there, in writing the polynomial. I have edited it. Is it okay now?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! @marty cohen

Comment: One way to express your appreciation, Simran, is to "accept" marty's answer by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: Oh, alright! Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a start, if
$f(x)
=5\sqrt{x} + 37x^{1/27} - 1
$,
$f(0) = -1$
and
$f(1) = 41
$,
so there is a root there.

If $x = 1/25$,
$5\sqrt{x} = 1$
so $f(1/25) > 0$,
so the root is in
$(0, 1/25)$.

Looking at the other term,
if
$x = (1/37)^{27}
\approx 4.56\cdot 10^{-43}
$,
$f((1/37)^{27}) > 0$
so the root is between $0$
and
this.

Now apply Newton
or some other iteration
to get a more accurate estimate.